# modifying data in a node

Tags: entities

I have created a node with a cck select box which comes with a few possible values. How would I code a module to change the value from one value to another? For example, the default value of field_model is Oldsmobile, and I want to write code which will change it to Toyota?

Answer (score 0):

This depends ... D6 or D7 ... is the field a reference to something else (term, node, entity)?

Generally you have to write something that looks up the value of the item in the list, for example for a node reference:

```
  $modelcode='Toyota';      

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->fieldCondition('field_models_code', 'value', $modelcode, '=');
  $result = $query->execute();
  $model_nid=array_shift(array_keys($result['node']));

  unset($result);
  unset($query);
```

Then you would take the $model_nid and update your field in the form state:

```
$form_state['values']['field_model'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $model_nid;
```

This example assumes D7 and a field set to node reference.

Comment: I am actually using D6 and I am using a simple text field with a select list. How could I update the field?

Comment: Are you setting the field in a hook_form_alter()?